# Phonegapbuild needs .db file for adding a key for blackberry platform

Tags: cordova, blackberry, phonegap-build, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to sign my Blackberry app build in HTML5/CSS3/JAVASCRIPT using PhoneGap-Build.

I got the csk file from the Blackberry website however phonegap also needs a .db file what is that exactly ? and how do i generate .db file for blackberry ?

Also with the csk key which version will it run on in blackberry i was hoping it should be fine for all version since it was build in HTML5/CSS3/JAVASCRIPT?